Total Commander - how to open two panels from the command line
I have a project where I need to work with directories, one by one, where each one has a known "twin" that I need to move files to.
I want to create a script that will list the directories and their twins so I will copy a command from a text file, paste it to the command line and both directories will open in the two panels.

This is how the commands look like.
TOTALCMD64.EXE /o /L="C:\Dropbox\Books\Version-1\Chapter-1" /R="C:\Dropbox\Books\Version-2\Chapter-1"

TOTALCMD64.EXE /o /L="C:\Dropbox\Books\Version-1\Chapter-2" /R="C:\Dropbox\Books\Version-2\Chapter-2"

TOTALCMD64.EXE /o /L="C:\Dropbox\Books\Version-1\Chapter-3" /R="C:\Dropbox\Books\Version-2\Chapter-3"

You can prepare a script that will create a text file with those commands. Copy one line, paste it in the command line at the bottom of Total Commander and the panels will open.
After you finish with those panels, delete the line from the text file so you know you are done.
